# How can I reuse code from one JavaScript file in another?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I had 2 JavaScript files, f1.js and f2.js respectively and one HTML page called index.html.

I use the script tag to use the code from f1.js in my index.html. But, I want f1.js to use some code from f2.js. So, the hierarchy is like this -
index.html <--- f1.js <--- f2.js.

i.e. f2.js is a pseudo-random generator and has a function which creates a random seed, and I want to use this in my code for f1.js.

Code example:

index.html - how I call f1.js in the html page (my code)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="f1.js">
</script>
```

f1.js - my code

```
function hello() {
    Math.seedrandom("1"); // this is the method I want to reuse from f2.js
    alert("hello: " + Math.random());
}
```

f2.js - code I want to use (via the link below)

```
Math.seedrandom();
```

How can I do this?

Edit: the file I want to reuse can be found her - http://davidbau.com/encode/seedrandom.js

It's a custom random seed generator tool which has a function: Math.seedrandom("") that I want to use.

Comment: Generally - Including f2.js before f1.js will work. However, if you have modularized the js then you need different approach. Try the obvious solution first if it works then great else you will need to code snippet of files.

Comment: Is the random seed function available globally from f2, or does the API for the generator allow access to that function? If so, put the call to f2 before the call to f1 in your HTML file, and call the function from f1.

Comment: @nikhil Hey, thanks for the swift response. I've tried a few methods but none seem to work. I'm basically trying to import/use a file that deals with random seed generation that is written by someone else, in my own JS code.

Comment: @Andy I've tested the function on its own but just having trouble getting it to work with getting my JS file to call it. The file I want to use code from is this - http://davidbau.com/encode/seedrandom.js Which has a method called "Math.seedrandom()" which is what I want to use.

Comment: @user1930227, [this readme is easier to read](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom). [Here's the relevant bit](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom#script-tag-usage). Just add that script call to your HTML, add the script call to f2.js under it, then use it as described in that highlighted section.

Comment: @Andy Yup, already tried that and it worked; but it would mean that I'd have to move all of my code from f1.js into the script tag in index.html right? Is there no way to do that, but directly in f1.js? Because, f1.js is what will be using that code and I only really intended to have the one script tag in my HTML which called f1.js.

Comment: Why don't you want more than one JS call? Anyway, if you just want to have f1, [just copy this code](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom/blob/released/seedrandom.min.js) to the top of f1 _before any other code_ and it should work.

Comment: @Andy I didn't think there was a need to make more than one JS call. I basically want to do the equivalent of an import statement in java. But appreciate this, will give it a shot :)

Comment: If you want imports likes in Java - you need to use browserify or webpack. In classic JavaScript there is no other way to import than <script> tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a global module pattern:

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <script src="f1.js"></script>
    <script src="f2.js"></script>
</head>
```

**f1.js**

```
function hello() {
    //some stuff
}
```

**f2.js**

```
(function(privateHello) {//now it's private

    privateHello(); //invoke private instance

})(hello); //inject global variable
```

If you don't like this pattern, look into [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), or a backend bundler like browserify or webpack.

The global module pattern might be used more like this, however.

**f1.js**

```
var _functions = (function() {
    return {
        fn_a: function() { /* do something */ },
        fn_b: function() { /* do something else */ }
    };
})();
```

**fs2.js**

```
(function(methods) {
    methods.fn_a(); //do something
    methods.fn_b(); //do something else
})(_functions);
```

Comment: I personally recommend browserify - for clean plain code (unlike require.js) and simplicity (unlike webpack)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this what you want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.3.10/seedrandom.min.js>
</script>
<script>
  function hello(){
    Math.seedrandom("1");
    alert("hello: " + Math.random());
  }
</script>
<button onclick="hello()">Run seedrandom</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is, link the html to the f1.js file first, and then link it to the f2.js file. This will allow you to call the function from the f1.js file. But make sure to implement f2.js first.

Comment: @Rishi Thanks for the response! I've included the file whose code I want to reuse in the body of the question above. So you're saying, I use the script tag to load that first, then load my own JSfile?